# how can I show the scanned url array of the site instantly on the client side?

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

I'm scanning the site's sitemap using apollo server. but when I send the request from playground, it gives results without waiting for the function to finish. How can I hold the scan for a result? And how can I show the scanned url array of the site instantly on the client side?

If I use graphql subscription, I need to save the data one by one. this would be a lot of data.

Note: the system is working and data is being saved in mongoose.

```
scanSitemap: async (parent, { id, data }, { WebLink }) => {

    let dataset = [];

    const generator = await SitemapGenerator('https://example.org', {
      stripQuerystring: false,
      filepath: null
    });

    generator.start();

    generator.on('add', (url) => {
      dataset.push(url);
      console.log(dataset);
    });

    generator.on('done', () => {
      return new WebLink({
        status: 1, domain: 'test', websiteId: id, urls: dataset
      }).save();
    });

  },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, your `scanSitemap` resolver needs to return a `Promise` that resolves only when the `'done'` event is emitted from `SitemapGenerator`

Why? Well, according to the ApolloServer Docs:

> Resolvers often *perform asynchronous actions*, such as fetching from a database or back-end API. To support this, a resolver can return a promise that resolves to any other supported return type. (https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/resolvers/#return-values)

In this case, your resolver is definitely performing an asynchronous operation -- **sitemap scraping** -- so this is a good situation to use Promises.

By returning a `Promise`, you are instructing Apollo Server to wait for the results of your asynchronous operation to be available. According to your code, I believe you want to resolve this at the end of the day:

```
new WebLink({
  status: 1, domain: 'test', websiteId: id, urls: dataset
}).save()
```

I have rewritten your code to use Promises (I also tested it on my end, and it works!)

```
scanSitemap: async (parent, { id, data }, { WebLink }) => {
  // Returning a new promise inside of the GraphQL resolver
  // that accepts a callback with a resolve argument that we'll use later
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    let dataset = [];

    // No need to await SitemapGenerator
    const generator = SitemapGenerator('https://example.org', {
      filepath: null,
      stripQuerystring: false,
    });

    generator.start();

    generator.on('add', (url) => {
      dataset.push(url);
      console.log(dataset);
    });

    generator.on('done', () => {
      // Resolving the promise
      // and telling ApolloServer that our GraphQL resolver result is ready
      resolve(
        new WebLink({
          domain: 'test',
          status: 1,
          urls: dataset,
          websiteId: id,
        }).save(),
      );
    });
  });
};
```

Here is a great resource about Promises in case you're interested further:

https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-promises-async-await-5gke